# Oracle connection Error: identifier resolution

Tags: oracle, pdo

i'm using `WAMP` and `Oracle 11g`. `PHP` work fines in normal queries of getting data. but when i tries to implement the same code in PDO (PHP) it gives me error in connection

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S02]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:631)
```

connection string is

```
$username='user';
$password='12345';
try {
$conn = new PDO('oci:host=localhost:8080/XE;dbname=databank', $username, $password);
//$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970261/connect-oracle-with-pdo-with-sid-and-instance-name) might interest you.

Comment: Pretty sure the `host=` part is going to be invalid, and the `dbname=databank` looks like it's come from another RDBMS, maybe. The linked question probably does show how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following line of code

```
$conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost:8080/XE', $username, $password);
```

Here it is assumed 8080 is your oracle db port (generally this port is 1521)